# Rewriting function using Euler's equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have tasked with rewriting the following function using Euler's equation into an expression where it is easier to find the indefinite integral

[image]

I have no idea where to even begin here. I think I have to make use of the fact that Euler's equation can be rewritten into:

[image]

Can anyone give a hint in the right direction here?

Comment: Hint: replace $x$ with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$2\cos(16t)\cos(6t) = \cos(22t)+\cos(10t).$$
Next use Euler's formula to get that 
$$\cos(22t)+\cos(10t) = \frac{e^{22it}+e^{-22it}}{2}+\frac{e^{10it}+e^{-10it}}{2}.$$

Recall that 
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
and 
$$\cos(a-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b).$$
So 
$$\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)=2\cos(a)\cos(b).$$

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I can't seem to figure out why 2cos(16t)cos(6t)=cos(22t)+cos(10t). is valid. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: See the edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: It sure does, thanks.